# Is it safe for the IC to connect the LED to the logic output

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, current, integrated-circuit

Is it safe for the [CD4029B](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd4029b) to connect the LEDs to the logic outputs, if the datasheet says that the 'output high current (source)' is 3mA?

I don't understand if LED 'tries' to draw more current than it is available or the IC acts as a resistor and limits the LEDs current consumption.

Comment: With the advent of high brightness leds, with some you can get adequate brightness with 1 or 2mA. If you require more, then you’d want to add a suitable driver chip, mosfet or bjt to handle the current.

Comment: Poor IC. Please add a resistor in series.

Answer (score 2):

That 3 mA is the current for which a certainu output voltage is guaranteed. (Or, for that output voltage, this current is guaranteed.)

MOSFETs behave like resistors (for not too large currents), but that resistance usually is small enough so that it is possible for the output to burn up if you do not limit the current.

For the circuit to be safe, look at the absolute maximum ratings: the power dissipation (in the MOSFET, not in the LED) must be at most 100 mW per output.

Figures 3 and 4 of the datasheet show how the output behaves:

[image: CD4029B typical output high characteristics]

[image: CD4029B minimum output high characteristics]

Assuming that the supply voltage is 15 V, and that you connect a LED with a forward voltage of 2.5 V, the remaining 12.5 V must be dropped over the output transistor. So the output current is typically 29 mA, and at least 14 mA.

29 mA × 12.5 V = 362.5 mW, which is way too high.
So you have to add a series resistor.

But with a supply voltage of 5 V, the current is so small that it is safe even when the output is shorted to ground.

Answer (score 0):

Like all MOSFETs , CMOS FETs are voltage controlled resistors and the CD4xxx series being high voltage the original series, are high resistance RdsOn which increases as Vdd reduces.

If you compute the Vol/Iol at some Vdd, you can estimate the nominal and tolerance of Zol and similar for Zoh.  You will be limited by power dissipation and the absolute max current specs by design so use some margin.

For indicators, that is a reasonable choice.

As CMOS families migrated faster with lower voltages and smaller lithography, the RdsOn for 5V technology reduced RdsOn as the ratio of Vdd max/min was reduced with an appropriate threshold voltage for Vt such that the Zout ranges from approx 33 to 66 Ohms as I recall.  The Z for 3.6Vmax family is about half that. I recommend you do the math to verify my assertions.